# Are algebraic groups functors exact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, functors

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field (for example $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}$). An algebraic group $G$ can be thought of as a functor from $\mathbb{K}$-algebras to groups. Is $G$ exact, i.e. does it preserve exact sequences? Does it preserve inclusions? Does it preserve surjections?

References are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as an exact sequence of $K$-algebras. The functor associated to an algebraic group generally does not preserve surjections. For example, there is a surjection $\mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{Q}[i]$, but applying $GL_1(-)$ produces a map

$$\mathbb{Q}^{\times} \cong GL_1(\mathbb{Q}[x]) \to GL_1(\mathbb{Q}[i]) \cong \mathbb{Q}[i]^{\times}$$

which is not a surjection because e.g. its image does not contain $i$. On the other hand, the functor associated to an *affine* algebraic group, being representable, preserves all limits, which you can use to show that it preserves injections. So it is "left exact" in this case, although using these terms outside of the abelian context risks some misunderstandings.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!
Why are there no exact sequences of K-algebras? When you say abelian context, are you referring to abelian categories or abelian groups?

Comment: @Strichcoder: just try to write down what an exact sequence of $K$-algebras could possibly be. The leftmost algebra must be the kernel of an algebra homomorphism, hence an ideal, so if it's not the entire middle algebra it can't have a unit in such a way that the inclusion into the middle algebra is a homomorphism. And I mean abelian categories.